# Line equation that cross the origin and 2 lines

Tags: trigonometry

Given 2 lines r and s.

- r and s don't have an intersection point
- none of them touch the origin (0,0,0)
  What approach should I use to find the equation of the line that cross the origin and also cross r and s?

if necessary, we can consider r and s as:

```
    x = at + d                  x = gt + j
r:  y = bt + e              s:  y = ht + k
    z = ct + f                  z = it + l
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it a vectors: $\vec r = \vec a t + \vec b$ and $\vec r = \vec c t + \vec d$ (note that I am using $\vec r$ as the position vector $(x, y, z)$, not as a label for the line - $\vec r$ is the conventional letter to use for this purpose). The origin and the line r form a plane. To find the equation for that plane, we need to find a normal vector to it. The easiest way to do this is to take the cross-product of two vectors in that plane. But $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ fit this bill (do you understand why?). So our normal vector is $\vec n = \vec a \times \vec b$, and the equation of that plane is $\vec n \cdot \vec r = 0$, since the plane passes through the origin.

Now, just find the intersection of this plane with the other line s: $\vec n \cdot (\vec c t + \vec d) = 0$, which solves to $ t_0 = -\frac{\vec n \cdot \vec d}{\vec n \cdot \vec c}$. If the denominator is 0, then the two lines are parallel, and the entire plane intersects both lines. Otherwise it gives you a value for $t_0$ that can be plugged into the equation for s to get the point of intersection $\vec p = \vec c t_0 + \vec d$. The line you want is $\vec r = \vec p t$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\vec r(u)=u\vec a + \vec b$ and  $\vec s(v)=v\vec c + \vec d$

then the equation of any line passing through both lines can be expressed as

$$\vec l(w)=\vec r(u) + w(\vec r(u)-\vec s(v))$$

We seek values of $u$ and $v$ for which there is a value of $w$ for which $\vec l(w)=(0,0,0)$

This requires that 
$$w\vec s(v)=(w+1) \vec r(u)  $$

so that $\vec s(v)$ and $\vec r(u)$ must be parallel

You could solve the problem by solving the equation $\vec r(u) = k \vec s(v)$ as a system of three equations and three unknowns.

or solve

$$\vec r(u)  \times \vec s(v) =0$$

$$(u\vec a + \vec b)  \times (v\vec c + \vec d) =0$$

$$uv(\vec a\times \vec c)+ u(\vec a\times \vec d)+ v(\vec b\times \vec c) +(\vec b\times \vec d)  =0$$

now take the scalar product of the whole equation with the vector $\vec c $ and uase the fact that $(\vec a\times \vec c) \cdot \vec c = (\vec b\times \vec c) \cdot \vec c=0$

$$ u(\vec a\times \vec d)\cdot \vec c+ (\vec b\times \vec d)\cdot \vec c  =0$$

You can now evaluate $u$ and your line will be $\vec l (w) =w\vec r(u)$